CFL criterion for a PDE
Given the PDE
$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \frac{\partial^2 \Psi}{\partial x^2}+ \beta \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x} + U \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{\partial^2 \Psi}{\partial x^2}=0$
with fixed $\beta$ and $U$ .
The spatial initial condition is given as $\Psi(x, t=0)$.
A numerical solution for $\Psi_j^n$ (n=time, j=space) is found by rewriting it
$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t} = -\beta \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x} - U \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{\partial^2 \Psi}{\partial x^2} $
As discretization scheme, for each timestep n this Poisson equation is first solved numerically based on already known $\Psi_j^n$, resulting in
$F_j^n = \frac{\partial \Psi_j^n}{\partial t} $
for all spatial grid points (j).
On the RHS of the Poisson equation above, for the second spatial derivative the known centered approximation is used:
$\Psi_{xx}(x_i, t_n)\approx \frac{\Psi_{i+1}+\Psi_{i-1}-2 \Psi_i}{\Delta x^2}$
The gradients are calculated with the centered scheme
$\frac{\partial U_{j}}{\partial x} \approx \frac{U_{j+1}-U_{j-1}}{2 \Delta x}$
Afterwards, a central difference update for the next time step n+1 is carried out:
$\Psi_j^{n+1} = \Psi_j^{n-1} + 2 \Delta t F_j^n$
It turns out "experimentally", that the following Courant-Friedrichs-Lewy (CFL) Stability Criterion can be applied as requirement for stable numerical solutions:
$\Delta x/\Delta t \ge U $
Why is it that simple? It is not obvious for me, that the constant $U$ in the PDE is the relevant quantity (velocity) to be used in the CFL criterion. Can it be justified?

I don't understand how you got from $\partial_{xx} F = - \beta \partial_x \Psi - U \partial_{xxx} \Psi$ to your final discretization. How are you discretizing $\partial_x \Psi$? Did you mean this to be $\partial_{xx} F$? How are you discretizing the first and third derivative w.r.t. x of $\Psi$? Why do you even need to take any derivatives of $U$?

I assume that the selection of $U$ in the first derivative is unfortunate. Considering the information in the post, I get the following difference equation:
$$w_{i+1}^{n+1} + w_{i-1}^{n+1} - 2 w_{i}^{n+1} = w_{i+1}^{n-1} + w_{i-1}^{n-1} - 2 w_{i}^{n-1} - F_1 [w_{i+1}^{n} - w_{i-1}^{n}] - F_2 [w_{i+2}^{n} + w_{i-2}^{n} - 2 w_{i + 1}^{n+1} - 2 w_{i + 1}^{n+1}],  ,$$
with $F_1 = \beta \Delta x \Delta t$ and $F_2 = U\Delta t / \Delta x$. This implies that the first iteration in time has to be done different since it depends on the last two instants.

@helloworld922 Yes, you are right, what I wrote was partly a mess: For each timestep first a Poisson-Solver is used to calculate $F$ out of $\Psi$ and then F is used to move forward in time.  U is just a constant, I mixed it up with a general variable for which derivatives are calculated in discretized schemes.  I should have better explained what I did, but I didn't want to write a big question on the other hand. I will re-formulate the whole question because you can't guess what I did in detail.

You mention discretization for $\frac{dU}{dx}$ but I don't see where that term appears.

You could view this as an advection equation for the quantity $G:=\frac{d^2 \Psi}{dx^2}$, i.e.
$$\partial_t G + U \partial_x G = -\beta \partial_x \Psi$$
with the term on the RHS computed via a Poisson solve from G. From this perspective $U$ is evidently the relevant wave speed for the CFL condition of the time evolution, not withstanding any stability requirements of the algorithm used to find $\Psi$ given $G$.
